# MEL Expression Issues

Tags: mule, mel

I have defined a global function as below

```
<configuration doc:name="Configuration">
    <expression-language autoResolveVariables="true">
        <import class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat" />
        <global-functions>
            def convertDate(shiftDate){
                dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                return dateFormat.format(shiftDate);
            }            
        </global-functions>         
    </expression-language>
</configuration>
```

But when calling via logger nothing seems to happen

```
<logger message="Convert Date #[convertDate(xpath://address/@timestamp)]" level="DEBUG" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

The xpath expression xpath://address/@timestamp yields 2014-10-29T15:23:07

But before the logger I see

xpath-branch:/address/@timestamp is: org.dom4j.tree.DefaultAttribute@6452310a [Attribute: name timestamp value "2014-10-29T15:23:07"]

The error message is as below

```
org.mule.api.expression.InvalidExpressionException: [Error: unexpected end of statement]
[Near : {... convertDate(xpath://address/@payloadID) ....}]
```

What am I doing wrong here? Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing MEL and the old style of expressions.

This is old style: `xpath://address/@payloadID`

This is MEL: `xpath('//address/@payloadID').value`

So you need to use:

```
<logger
   message="Convert Date #[convertDate(xpath('//address/@payloadID').value)]"
   level="DEBUG" />
```

See: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+Tips#MuleExpressionLanguageTips-XPathSupport